# Loading all assets with Async task-Libgdx

Tags: android-asynctask, libgdx

I want to load all my assets in an Async task.
I don't have clear idea about this and also not able to find any relevant example from net.

It looks like using AssetManager is the best way to load assets at once.
But I have some assets like dragon bone animations,that is not possible to be loaded by AssetManager.

I have created an interface like this:

```
public interface IAsyncCallBack {

  public abstract void WorkToDo();     
  public abstract void onFinish();

 }
```

In MyGdxClass's create method I am defining the method body:

```
   final AsyncCallBack callback = new AsyncCallBack() {

        @Override
        public void WorkToDo() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loadAssets();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
         isLoaded = true;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

     };
```

But I have no idea about creating AsyncTask with LibGdx and loading assets with it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would still recommend using AssetManager as you can write your own asset loader using https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/AsynchronousAssetLoader.html

Comment: @dfourWill you please add an example for AsynchronusAssetLoader?I couldn't find any.

Comment: The examples are the source code of the existing loaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the libgdx AsynchronousAssetLoader interface to define your own loader. This code is taken from the BitmapFont Loader which loads a font and has extra files which require loading.

```
package com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetDescriptor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoaderParameters;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.BitmapFontData;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException;

/** {@link AssetLoader} for {@link BitmapFont} instances. Loads the font description file (.fnt) asynchronously, loads the
 * {@link Texture} containing the glyphs as a dependency. The {@link BitmapFontParameter} allows you to set things like texture
 * filters or whether to flip the glyphs vertically.
 * @author mzechner */
public class BitmapFontLoader extends AsynchronousAssetLoader<BitmapFont, BitmapFontLoader.BitmapFontParameter> {
    public BitmapFontLoader (FileHandleResolver resolver) {
        super(resolver);
    }

    BitmapFontData data;

    @Override
    public Array<AssetDescriptor> getDependencies (String fileName, FileHandle file, BitmapFontParameter parameter) {
        Array<AssetDescriptor> deps = new Array();
        if (parameter != null && parameter.bitmapFontData != null) {
            data = parameter.bitmapFontData;
            return deps;
        }

        data = new BitmapFontData(file, parameter != null ? parameter.flip : false);
        if (parameter != null && parameter.atlasName != null) {
            deps.add(new AssetDescriptor(parameter.atlasName, TextureAtlas.class));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.getImagePaths().length; i++) {
                String path = data.getImagePath(i);
                FileHandle resolved = resolve(path);

                TextureLoader.TextureParameter textureParams = new TextureLoader.TextureParameter();

                if (parameter != null) {
                    textureParams.genMipMaps = parameter.genMipMaps;
                    textureParams.minFilter = parameter.minFilter;
                    textureParams.magFilter = parameter.magFilter;
                }

                AssetDescriptor descriptor = new AssetDescriptor(resolved, Texture.class, textureParams);
                deps.add(descriptor);
            }
        }

        return deps;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadAsync (AssetManager manager, String fileName, FileHandle file, BitmapFontParameter parameter) {
    }

    @Override
    public BitmapFont loadSync (AssetManager manager, String fileName, FileHandle file, BitmapFontParameter parameter) {
        if (parameter != null && parameter.atlasName != null) {
            TextureAtlas atlas = manager.get(parameter.atlasName, TextureAtlas.class);
            String name = file.sibling(data.imagePaths[0]).nameWithoutExtension().toString();
            AtlasRegion region = atlas.findRegion(name);

            if (region == null)
                throw new GdxRuntimeException("Could not find font region " + name + " in atlas " + parameter.atlasName);
            return new BitmapFont(file, region);
        } else {
            int n = data.getImagePaths().length;
            Array<TextureRegion> regs = new Array(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                regs.add(new TextureRegion(manager.get(data.getImagePath(i), Texture.class)));
            }
            return new BitmapFont(data, regs, true);
        }
    }

    /** Parameter to be passed to {@link AssetManager#load(String, Class, AssetLoaderParameters)} if additional configuration is
     * necessary for the {@link BitmapFont}.
     * @author mzechner */
    static public class BitmapFontParameter extends AssetLoaderParameters<BitmapFont> {
        /** Flips the font vertically if {@code true}. Defaults to {@code false}. **/
        public boolean flip = false;

        /** Generates mipmaps for the font if {@code true}. Defaults to {@code false}. **/
        public boolean genMipMaps = false;

        /** The {@link TextureFilter} to use when scaling down the {@link BitmapFont}. Defaults to {@link TextureFilter#Nearest}. */
        public TextureFilter minFilter = TextureFilter.Nearest;

        /** The {@link TextureFilter} to use when scaling up the {@link BitmapFont}. Defaults to {@link TextureFilter#Nearest}. */
        public TextureFilter magFilter = TextureFilter.Nearest;

        /** optional {@link BitmapFontData} to be used instead of loading the {@link Texture} directly. Use this if your font is
         * embedded in a {@link Skin}. **/
        public BitmapFontData bitmapFontData = null;

        /** The name of the {@link TextureAtlas} to load the {@link BitmapFont} itself from. Optional; if {@code null}, will look for
         * a separate image */
        public String atlasName = null;
    }
}
```

The main idea is to have a parameter class which defines all the extra parts required to load your asset and then in the load methods you create and return your asset object.